# Show that the limit exists for any $f$ in the Schwartz class and prove that the principal value, $p.v.(1/x)$ is a continuous functional.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $$[p.v.(1/x)]:=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}f(x)/xdx$$
Show that the limit exists for any $f\in S$ and prove that $p.v(1/x)$ is a continuous functional.

Comment: Replace $f$ by $f-f(0)e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @reuns Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: What does it change when replacing $f$ by $f-f(0)e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @reuns I’m not sure...

Comment: The integral becomes absolutely convergent

Comment: @reuns I still don't see the relation how that could help in proving that the $p.v.$ will converge.

Comment: I can't guess where you are stuck, that what will converge to what

Comment: @reuns so suppose there is a function $f_n$ that converges to $f-f(0)e^{-x^2}$. We know that $[p.v.(1/x)]f-f(0)e^{-x^2}$, where do I go from here?

Comment: Obviously you need to replace $f_n$ too. Do you understand that $\frac{f_n(x)}{x}$ is not integrable whereas $\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(0)e^{-x^2}}{x}$  is integrable ?

Comment: @reuns $\frac{f_n(x)}{x}$ is not integrable at $x=0$, but $\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(0)e^{x^2}}{x}$ is $0$ at $x=0$, so is integrable.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure how to tangibly go about proving the statement. I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to say that $f_n\to f\in S$

implies $f_n-f\to 0,x(f_n-f)\to 0$, $f_n'-f'\to 0$ in  $L^\infty$

implies $\frac{f(x)-f_n(x)-(f(0)-f_n(0))e^{-x^2}}{x} \to 0$ in $L^1$

implies $<pv(1/x),f_n>\ \to\ <pv(1/x),f>$.